# how do you write VBA code for changing font color based on cell fill color

Tags: excel, vba, formatting

I have a very large report that when someone is finished they fill the cell green (RGB 146,208,80). the font color maybe red due to a conditional formatting of <today()+7...I was trying to create a VBA code that I could use in the conditional formatting formula to create a new rule; Cell A2 =green change font to black.

Here is my attempt at the code:

```
Sub fillcolor(range)
Range ("A2").Select.inteior.color
Selection.RGB(146,208,80).Select.font.color=RGB(0,0,0)
EndSub
```

I believe if I write the VBA code I don't need a conditional formatting rule.

Please help!

Comment: You mean `Interior`

Comment: With you code (once it's corrected), you will set the font color of a cell. This is always overruled by a conditional formatting font color.

Comment: @FunThomas Could a conditional formatting rule then be created to solve?

Comment: Sure - if you know the rule? How could a formula "know" that the cell now should be displayed in green? Can you tell by it's value?

Comment: Perhaps if the VBA code finds the select interior color (green) True IFnot False...In Conditional Formatting. =fillcolor($A2)=True

Comment: That makes sense...As normally I would have a status column based on that then conditional format, but there are 42 columns and each would need its own status column to make a rule or value to follow....I see now as well I can' override a conditional formatting rule even manually. Super helpful..Learned something new

Comment: You can overpass the Condidional Formatting influence using `Range("A2").DisplayFormat.Interior.Color`. It will return the real cell interior column, even if it is the result of a conditional formatting rule.